# Interpreting Firebug and Chrome Inspect Element to Determine my CSS hyperlink issue

Tags: wordpress, css, firebug

I cannot get hyperlinks to show up as an overlay (or watermark) in front of an image, as they should.  Instead, I believe something is being overwritten by my WordPress theme's CSS, leaving plain HTML hyperlinks below the image.

**Here is what [my page](http://www.jasonpaulweber.com/smartway-responsive-blogger-template-blogger/) looks like:**

[image: Bad Results]

**But here's what it's supposed to look like:**

[image: Proper Results]

**Here is what Chrome Inspect Element is telling me ([Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOjG3.jpg)):**

[image: Chrome]

**Here is what Firebug is telling me ([Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjZeW.jpg)):**

[image: Firebug]

Unfortunately, I'm clueless with CSS.  I believe my WordPress default theme is overriding some important settings, but I'm unsure what/how to adjust things.  I can simply add !important clauses to things in my custom CSS, but I'm unsure as to what to put or how to put it.

Here is the [stylesheet associated with my website](http://www.jasonpaulweber.com/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/dynamik-min.css), and here is a website that has the [exact same thing I have](http://premiumfreewordpressthemes.org/gamma-mobile-retina-html5-and-css3-wordpress-mobile/), except it's functioning properly.

Any guidance in this regard would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: I cant see any CSS rule for your class="cashcow_preview_links". Why? This class is the parent div for links.

Comment: Hi Era.  The only thing I have is .cashcow_preview_links {
 text-align: center;
} .... it's in my dynamik-min.css

Comment: Hi Era ... you can view the stylesheet associated with this at http://www.jasonpaulweber.com/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/dynamik-min.css ... an example of a website that has the same thing, except it's working, is http://premiumfreewordpressthemes.org/gamma-mobile-retina-html5-and-css3-wordpress-mobile/ ....

Comment: Thanks, Era ... I found a solution.  I really just had to merge two separate stylesheets, and somehow found a way to manage to do so.

Comment: great.. you have done it..  (Y) ..